# A convex function over a Martingale is a Submartingale --- Proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

$\left\{ Z_{n},n\geq1\right\} $ is a martingale, which means that $\forall n$,
it satisfies the below two conditions,

1) This is the uniformly bounded condition.
$$
E\left[\left|Z_{n}\right|\right]<\infty
$$

2) Standard martingalge condition.
$$
E\left[\left.Z_{n+1}\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right]=Z_{n}
$$

$f$ is a convex function, then the proof that,
$\left\{f\left(Z_{n}\right),n\geq1\right\} $ is a submartingale goes as below.
This is from the book Stochastic Processes, Second Edition, Sheldon Ross, Lemma 6.4.3, page 314.

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.f\left(Z_{n+1}\right)\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right] & \geq & f\left(E\left[\left.Z_{n+1}\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right]\right)\\
 & = & f\left(Z_{n}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

## Question:

How do we know that, $f\left(Z_{n}\right)$, is uniformly bounded for it to be a submartingale? That is, what extra assumption do we need to make or is there another result that gives the below? Please give full details and steps.
$$
E\left[\left| f\left(Z_{n}\right)\right|\right]<\infty
$$

If I am overlooking something basic, please point out.

Answer (score 2):

It is only a local martingale in general.

For example, you can take standard Brownian motion, and the convex function to be $exp(x^4)$ (it's a convex function followed by a non decreasing convex function, so is again convex). Then the expectation of this process is infinite at any nonzero time - just compute it explicitly using LOTUS.

Or, since you are using discrete time, you can use the random walk with iid normal(0,1) steps as the martingale, and the same convex function.

(By the way - you don't need the bound on L1 to be uniform in time. For example, you definitely  want a simple random walk to be a martingale, but the L1 norms are increasing as time goes on.  Not sure if that's what you intended or not.)