# A confusion in the proof of-"A convex function over a Martingale is a Submartingale."

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $\left\{ Z_{n},n\geq1\right\} $ is a (discrete) martingale, $f$ is a convex function. Now, we want to prove that $\{f(Z_n),n\geq1\}$ is a submartingale.

As it is stated in [A convex function over a Martingale is a Submartingale --- Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287798/a-convex-function-over-a-martingale-is-a-submartingale-proof), the proof can be written as \begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.f\left(Z_{n+1}\right)\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right] & \geq & f\left(E\left[\left.Z_{n+1}\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right]\right)\\
 & = & f\left(Z_{n}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

My question is: why can we check 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.f\left(Z_{n+1}\right)\right|Z_{1},\ldots,Z_{n}\right] & \geq 
 & = & f\left(Z_{n}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
instead of 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[\left.f\left(Z_{n+1}\right)\right|f(Z_{1}),\ldots,f(Z_{n})\right] & \geq 
 & = & f\left(Z_{n}\right)?
\end{eqnarray*}
Since now,  $\{f(Z_n),n\geq1\}$ should be seen as a stochastic process.

Comment: There must be a filtration associated with the sequence $\{Z_n\}$. Is it the natural one?

Comment: @d.k.o. I don't think so. In the book "An introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations" by Evans, the martingale is defined by: Let $X_1,...,X_n$... be a sequence of real-valued random variables. If $X_k=E(X_j|X_1,...,X_k)$ for all $j\geq k$, we call $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ a discrete martingale.

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#General_definition).

Comment: @d.k.o Do you mean the general definition? But why can't we use the basic definition here?

Comment: How do you show that 
$$
\mathsf{E}[Z_{n+1}\mid f(Z_1),\ldots,f(Z_n)]=Z_n \quad\text{a.s.?}
$$

Comment: Yes, I think that is the step where I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result should be stated as follows:

> Suppose that $\{Z_n\}$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)\}$ and $f$ is a convex function. Then $\{f(Z_n)\}$ is a submartingale w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$.

Comment: I agree with this statement. I was not sure about this since the book does not mention "w.r.t" a fixed sigma algebra. Thank you very much.